# What determines the cipher suite?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, mbedtls

I am using `mbedtls` on my TLS application. I've a question about the cipher suites.
When I debug my process, I get below lines from server side:

```
selected ciphersuite: TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
```

What is the reason for selecting this `CHACHA20-POLY1305` cipher ? Key? or certificate? or something else?

How can I change my chipher suite to `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the reason for selecting this CHACHA20-POLY1305 cipher

The ciphers supported by the server and by the client, including their preferences. Thus it depends on client and server configurations and on their TLS stacks.

> How can I change my chipher suite to TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256?

The `RSA` in the currently chosen cipher suite means that an RSA certificate was used for authentication. The `ECDSA` in the cipher you want means that the server needs to use a ECDSA certificate instead, i.e. you cannot achieve this with an RSA certificate.

Some servers can use both a RSA and ECDSA certificate in which case the choice of certificate depends again on client and server configuration regarding supported ciphers, preference etc.